# Calcular Distancias Api Google Maps v3 Automaticamente em um Loop

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, jsp

Eu gostaria de calcular a distância entre dois pontos utilizando a api Google Maps V3 automaticamente sem a utilização de interface, e enviá-las para o java para processamento futuro. As coordenadas estão em um banco de dados MySQL.

Eu até estou conseguindo mas de uma por uma. Tenho que ficar atualizando a página e dar submits para que o resultado vá para o java, isso tudo manualmente. Gostaria de colocar tudo em um loop, só que a função do google é assíncrona e já tem um callback.

```
//Realiza o calculo das distancias e a detecção da localidade
//start,middle e end são coordenadas no formato do google    
function calculateDistances(start,middle,end) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [start,middle],
      destinations: [middle,end],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

//analiza o resultado retornado pela funcao service.getDistanceMatrix da api do google
function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var values = "";
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      values += origins[i] + "$" + destinations[i]+ "$" + results[i].distance.text + "$" + results[i].duration.text + "#";
    }
    //evnia o valor para o o formulario
    document.getElementById('distance').value = values;
  }
}
```

A api é em javascript e eu tenho que enviar as coordenadas (lat,lon), aguardar a resposta do servidor google e enviar para o servlet.

Existe alguma possibilidade disso dar certo?

Comment: Se vc tem a Latitude e a Longitude, e facil calcular:
Em PHP (mas é facil transformar) isso e feito assim:
http://www.phpsources.org/scripts459-PHP.htm

Answer (score 1):

O [spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt-br#spherical) da API V3 do google maps calcula isso para você, quando você passa um array de LatLng.

```
var polyLengthInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(polygon.getPath().getArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha, segue uma idéia simples : Trabalhe com um array de localidades. Faça a chamada que faz o retorno da distância controlando uma variável para este array.No final da sua função callback você incrementa a variável e compara com o limite do array. Se ainda não tiver chegado no último índice programe um timer para chamar a rotina de cálculo de distâncias mais uma vez, fazendo isto até chegar até a última posição. Funciona. Abraços.